# MYSQL NOT IN function - How to improve and get it faster

Tags: mysql

I have a CRM that one of the queries looks like this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb1.customerID 
  FROM sales_company AS tb1
 WHERE rdate BETWEEN '2016-02-01' 
                 AND '2016-02-14' 
   AND type='payment' 
   AND customerID 
              NOT IN (SELECT customerID 
                        FROM sales_company 
                       WHERE rdate < tb1.rdate 
                         AND type='payment' 
                       GROUP BY customerID) 
 GROUP BY customerID`
```

With this query, I'm getting how much NEW customers has paid for their first time in the period in the query.

The issue:
I have a lot of tables with every company so I need to run this query around 30 times every refresh.

Yeah,
I know it's bad, this system I built is very old (7 years ago) and I cant touch her too much except change this query.

There is some good suggestion you guys know how to improve this query to get the number of rows at the end?

Thanks!

Comment: 30times every refresh? When the data refreshes, is there an interval or nightly? Is the NOT IN query taking to long for? Create a View with the Dates needed to cut down on the total table size. Going to need a little more to help.

Comment: the subquery is redundant in that context

Comment: Can you show the indexes definitions for the sales_company table?

Comment: I would ask What is the purpose of that subquery at all ?

Comment: Why are you using `DISTINCT` **and** `GROUP BY` the *same* field?

Comment: Hi, @JorgeCampos There is INDEX for all the fields I mention in the query below. Also There is no option to cut down the total size table because If customer joined to the system first time 3 years ago, and today he made his first purchase, I want to know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post the Table Type and the EXPLAIN of this and your query to see whats wrong.

```
EXPLAIN  SELECT DISTINCT tb1.customerID 
  FROM sales_company AS tb1
 WHERE rdate BETWEEN '2016-02-01' 
                 AND '2016-02-14' 
   AND TYPE='payment' 
   AND 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT customerID 
                        FROM sales_company 
                       WHERE customerID = tb1.customerID
                         AND rdate < tb1.rdate 
                         AND TYPE='payment' 
             ) 
GROUP BY customerID;
```

I have tested it with only 10000 rows

Comment: there is millions of rows, but I have tested your query + @juanvan recommendation regarding the total table, and it's working perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try:

```
SELECT customerID 
FROM sales_company 
WHERE type='payment'
GROUP BY customerID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN rdate BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-14' THEN 1 END) = 1 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN rdate < '2016-02-01' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

with an index on `(customerID, rdate)`.